# IQKeyboardManager iOS 13 memory issue and energy impact is high, app stucked with no logs

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13, iqkeyboardmanager

iOS 13 memory issue and energy impact is high, app stuck when trying to open pickerview or tapping textfield and can happen randomly on screen, I am running on real device(iPhone XR 13.2) Xcode 11.2

**BUG**
Memory issue and energy impact is high, app gets stuck when trying to open pickerview or tapping textfield and can happen randomly on screen on IQKEYBOARDMANAGER, I am running on real device(iPhone XR 13.2) Xcode 11.2
In this screen i have used Tableview and no other customisations have been done to IQKeyboardManager, if I disable IQKeyboardManager then it will work fine

**Expected behavior**
Energy impact should be low, Memory impact should be on low levels, app should not stuck or become irresponsive

**Error** : Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ljux.png)

**Versions**

**Xcode**: 11.2

**Mac OS**: 10.15.1

**Device**: iPhone XR

**OS Version**: iOS 13.2

**Library Version**: Latest, 6.5.3

Comment: You can open the issue on the repo itself!

Comment: I have already opened the issue in the repo, but it's been 3 days with no updates and it's urgent so I asked it here. @SohilR.Memon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had updated view's frame after `layoutSubviews()` which caused this issue as it goes on infinite loop.